# Icon flipping on hover

Tags: html, css

I want to flip icon on hover like [this](https://codepen.io/dmlb/pen/Aktzl) example. I copied and pasted code into my [pen](http://codepen.io/nazimkazim/pen/xOPyZR) and replaced own ids but it does not work. What is going wrong? Thanks in advance!

```
a #logo-img{ 
    margin: 3px 20px; 
    -webkit-transition: 0.6s ease-out;
    -moz-transition:  0.6s ease-out;
    transition:  0.6s ease-out;
  }

  &:hover {
    a #logo-img{
      -webkit-transform: rotateZ(720deg);
      -moz-transform: rotateZ(720deg);
      transform: rotateZ(720deg);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CSS syntax is off; it's like you wanted to write SCSS or something. With modifying it to

```
a #logo-img{ 
    margin: 3px 20px; 
    -webkit-transition: 0.6s ease-out;
    -moz-transition:  0.6s ease-out;
    transition:  0.6s ease-out;
}

a #logo-img:hover {
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(720deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateZ(720deg);
  transform: rotateZ(720deg);
}
```

it will work.

Comment: I'm glad I could help :)